# TFS 2013 view files and folders in TWA

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2013 which is connected to VS 2013. In the source control explorer, I've mapped folders to projects and it displays all the necessary files in VS so should I be able to view the associated files in TWA under the code tab when I navigate to the correct project? When I say files, I just mean the file name and folders not the actual source code or have I configured it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with setting my access level to advanced, I also checked "add to source control" on new projects and added it to existing projects and finally checked them in.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Access Level in TWA.  If you're defaulting to a Stakeholder then you wouldn't be able to see source code.

Go into the admin page for TWA, click Control Panel in the top left and select the Access Levels tab or navigate to:
http://yourserver:8080/tfs/_admin/_licences

Stakeholder may be the default so add yourself to Basic or Advanced (or set as default) and try again.